# Azure Stream Analytics JOIN only when certain device sends update

Tags: azure, join, azure-stream-analytics

I have three devices sending data to my Azure IoT Hub that I would like to join inside a Stream Analytics Job - but only when device1 is sending an update. All other events should be dropped.

The devices send updates in different frequencies:

- device1 every 5 seconds
- device2 every 10 seconds
- device3 every minute

The join is working fine, but I'm getting way too many output events (sometimes ~20 times the input events).

```
WITH Device1 AS (
    SELECT *,
    FROM Input timestamp by EventEnqueuedUtcTime
    WHERE deviceType LIKE 'type1'
), Device2 AS (
    SELECT
           deviceId,
           deviceType,
           sensor,
           EventEnqueuedUtcTime,     
           LAST(System.Timestamp()) OVER (PARTITION BY deviceId LIMIT DURATION(second, 10) WHEN deviceType LIKE 'type2' )
    FROM Input timestamp by EventEnqueuedUtcTime
    WHERE deviceType LIKE 'type2'
), Device3 AS (
    SELECT
           deviceId,
           deviceType,
           sensor,
           EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
           LAST(System.Timestamp()) OVER (PARTITION BY deviceId LIMIT DURATION(minute, 2) WHEN deviceType LIKE 'type3' )
    FROM Input timestamp by EventEnqueuedUtcTime
    WHERE deviceType LIKE 'type3'
), Calculated AS (
    SELECT 
       Device1,
       Device2,
       Device3,
       // TODO: some udf transformation
       DATEDIFF(millisecond, Device1.EventEnqueuedUtcTime, Device2.EventEnqueuedUtcTime) AS Device2Offset,
       DATEDIFF(millisecond, Device1.EventEnqueuedUtcTime, Device3.EventEnqueuedUtcTime) AS Device3Offset
    FROM Device1
    JOIN Device2
    ON DATEDIFF(second, Device1, Device2) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
    JOIN Device3
    ON DATEDIFF(minute, Device1, Device3) BETWEEN 0 AND 2
)

SELECT * INTO Output FROM Calculated
```

The output should look something like this:

```
{
    "Device1": {
        "deviceType": "type1",
        "deviceId": "1",
        "sensor1": 123,
        "sensor2": 456,
        "sensor3": 789
    },
    "Device2": {
        "deviceType": "type2",
        "deviceId": "2",
        "sensor1": 123
    },
    "Device3": {
        "deviceId": "3",
        "deviceType": "type3",
        "sensor1": 123
        "sensor2": 456
    }
    "Device2Offset": 2063,
    "Device3Offset": 212
}
```

Comment: To clarify, every time device1 sends an update, you want to include only the latest values of device2 and device3? Could you provide a sample of how the output should be formatted?

Comment: yes, exactly. I've added a sample output how it could look like