# When is a Stream Analytics job without Window getting triggered

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm unclear on when exactly a Stream Analytics job is getting called if I don't specify any [windowing function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions). Is it running periodically or is it getting called whenever a new event arrives? Unfortunately I haven't found any documentation specifically mentioning this yet.

Background: I have multiple devices sending updates to my IoT Hub and I only want to do a new calculation whenever a certain device sends an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a windowing function, your Azure Stream Analytics job will run every time an input message is received. However, it might batch the output depending on the egress rate. This depends on the type of the output as well, as described on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#output-batch-size).

One sidenote is that depending on how complex your query is, you need to take the Streaming Units usage into account. Even if you're not looking at windowed functions, you want to check [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-streaming-unit-consumption) if you want to use UDF's or reference data, as it might affect your memory usage.

Comment: makes sense, thx. Is there an easy way to get the event that triggered the job to see which device it originated from?

Comment: If your goal is to see the device ID, you can [include the device id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196896/how-to-separate-data-from-multiple-devices-on-microsoft-azure-stream-analytics/63207633#63207633) in the output. The device id is in the metadata of the event.

Comment: here's my full issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265198/azure-stream-analytics-join-only-when-certain-device-sends-update 
I tried limiting the output by querying the device id, but I still end up with way too many output events. I guess this question can be considered as answered, though.